# Difference between Propositional logic and First Order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Can you tell me what is the difference between Propositional logic and First Order logic.This is one my my exam question in AI can you help me to do that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formal logic without connection to programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In propositional logic you are allowed to use the usual propositional connectives (and, or, ...). In first order logic you are allowed to quantify (forall, exist) over variables, which makes it strictly more expressive.